# When does the cachemodel in ibatis re-query the database to get updated records?

Tags: java, ibatis

hi;

I'm using ibatis and its cache model for the first time and i cant seem to figure out at what time will the cache be filled with new results, meaning whne will the query that i'm applying cache model on be executed again to fill the cache with new results. Does it require some sort of command to get the results again or will it be done automatically? any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://ibatis.apache.org/docs/dotnet/datamapper/ch03s08.html) explains, it depends on the `implementation` setting and the `CacheSize` you provide for the `cacheModel`.

You can choose from LRU (Least Recently Used), FIFO (First In First Out) and MEMORY implementations.

In LRU, for example 
if you have a CacheSize of 100,

> When the cache becomes full, the
>   object that was accessed least
>   recently will be removed from the
>   cache.

You can set these to tune your cache appropriately.

Also, [enabling the DEBUG flag in log4j for com.ibatis](http://phillips4jc.blogspot.com/2010/03/ibatis-cache-miss-part-1-validating.html) shows you whether or not there is a Cache `miss` or `retrieved` for each execution.

Comment: Beware that the referenced documentation is for .NET, whereas the question is tagged Java